# Putting SVG images at a particular coordinate in QGIS C++ API

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, svg, qgsmapcanvas

I am using QGIS C++/Python API for making a custom QGIS application. I am trying to import an SVG image at a particular coordinate(`QgsPointXY`) in `qgsmapcanvas`. Which classes should be used? I am very confused right now about its solution.QgsMapcanvas is working fine. I was able to use it for my application. This code is just a part of my application for the SVG image problem only.
here is my code snippet:

```
mMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas(centralWidget);
auto pnt1 =  QgsPointXY(78.034370, 30.334795);
sym1= new QgsMarkerSymbol();
sym1->setSize(0);
sym1->setColor(QColor(0,255,0));
svgicon = new  QgsSvgAnnotation(mMapCanvas);
svgicon->setFilePath(QString("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr-dev/svg/food/food_bar.svg"));
svgicon->setVisible(true);
svgicon->setFrameSizeMm(QSizeF(20,10));
svgicon->setMapPosition(pnt1);
svgicon->setFrameOffsetFromReferencePointMm(QPoint(0,0)); 
svgicon->setMarkerSymbol(sym1);
QgsMapCanvasAnnotationItem *i =new QgsMapCanvasAnnotationItem(svgicon,mMapCanvas);
```